# Custom rubble in Aptana not activated automatically

Tags: aptana

I am new to Aptana, so I could be missing something obvious. My problem in that bundle I created does not get activated when Aptana is loaded. I have to update date of the rubble.rb file for it to work.

```
touch ~/Documents/Aptana Rubles/ioncubeEncode.ruble
```

After I do that, for the rest of that Aptana session things are peachy.

I do not think it is relevant, but here is bundle code, which works just fine (when it works):

```
require 'ruble'
#Ruble::Logger.log_level = :trace

bundle do |bundle|
  bundle.author = "Sasha"
  bundle.copyright = "None"
  bundle.display_name = "Ioncube Encode"
  bundle.description = "Encode just saved php file form base_local to base folder"
end

command "Ioncube Encode" do |cmd|
  cmd.input = :document
  cmd.output = :output_to_console
  cmd.trigger = :execution_listener , "org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
  cmd.invoke do |ctx|
    source_path = ENV['TM_FILEPATH']
    ext = File.extname(source_path)
    if ext == '.php'
        if ( source_path =~ /base_local/)
                destination_path = source_path.sub('/base_local/','/base/')
                #CONSOLE.puts "Ioncube Encoding: " + source_path + " to " + destination_path
                exec="/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_encoder5 -v --optimize more --without-loader-check " + source_path + " -o " +destination_path + " 2>&1"
                IO.popen(exec, 'r+') do |io|
                        io.close_write
                        CONSOLE.puts  io.read
                end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

This might not seem like a big deal but it bothers me - a lot.